# Hiding three checkboxes out of four, if another one is checked

Tags: java, android

[image][image][image]There are 4 checkboxs in a dialog layout. I want to hide  or disable to be checked three other ones if the first checkbox is checked. But if all or one of the other three checkboxs is checked, the first checkbox must be hidden or disabled in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Get the references(ids) using `root.findViewById()` hold them in the list.
Now in the `onCheckChangeListener()` loop through the list and uncheck all except the selected one. or do whatever is your requirement with them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked)
        {
            // hide what you want example chkbox2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            // visualize what you have hidden in the if example chkbox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
   }
});
```